# predict arbitrary values using a statsmodels LikelihoodModel

Tags: python, statsmodels

disclaimer: I am new to statsmodels and what I intend to achieve is probably not an intended usecase. So please be gentle.

I am following a tutorial to predict number of commuters on the JetRail. (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/ thank you Gurchetan! very helpful).

Input data like this:

```
ID,Datetime,Count
0,25-08-2012 00:00,8
1,25-08-2012 01:00,2
...
```

...following the tutorial I use ARIMA to fit the model and predict values:

```
...
fit1 = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train.Count, order=(2, 1, 4),seasonal_order=(0,1,1,7)).fit()
fit1.predict(0,2)
0    0.000000
1    7.999470
2    2.000877
```

I understand that statsmodels is made to work with timeseries so the predictions follow the model of the timeseries used (every hour).

Now I want to predict the amount of passengers at say '25-08-2012 00:43'. Is there a way to 'extract the model' and predict values at arbitrary times?

I understand that this is not conformant with timeseries but maybe there is a chance to do what I want, too :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the model's resolution limited to the hour so it wouldn't be able to generate predictions by the minute. However, you could utilize linear interpolation between two predicted points to estimate the prediction at two points.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr is there another api or tool in Python that supports fitting and in-sample and out-sample predictions without the resolution-limitation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any libraries out there with those features. Otherwise, I would have said it.